# Can I tag Elastic Beanstalk application version using "AWS Elastic Beanstalk Deploy Application" devops task?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure-devops, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, azure-pipelines, amazon-iam

Our techops team is using tags to control AWS Role access. Our team is using a DevOps Release pipeline with the [AWS Elastic Beanstalk Deploy Application](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vsts/latest/userguide/elastic-beanstalk-deploy.html) DevOps task which deploys our app to ElasticBeanstalk.
However, I am hitting an issue as the **application versions** that get's deployed by the task are not tagged. The role that our techops team has set up (and is assumed by our pipeline, i.e. the agent that performs the release) has a condition like so in the policy:

```
"Condition": {
                "ForAnyValue:StringEquals": {
                    "aws:TagKeys": [
                        "Service"
                    ]
                },
                "StringLikeIfExists": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/Service": [
                        "${aws:PrincipalTag/Service}",
                        "${aws:PrincipalTag/Service}:*"
                    ]
                }
            }
```

This is the release pipeline I have:
[image]

This is the error that I get after running the pipeline:

```
AccessDenied: User: arn:aws:sts::accountid:assumed-role/Generic-Pipeline-Role/Myapp-dev-test-release is not authorized to perform:
elasticbeanstalk:CreateApplicationVersion on resource: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-west-2:accountid:applicationversion/myapp-Web/myapp (dev branch)_2.0.0272 - Release 01
```

Is there a way to configure the AWS Elastic Beanstalk Deploy Application DevOps task to tag the versions it deploys? I am suspecting this is causing the error.